# What is the word for an action that is "considered to be frowned upon"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an **adjective** to describe a behavior or action that is considered to be a faux pas, or is frowned upon.

> Picking your nose is [*word*].
>
> Wearing socks with sandals is [*word*].
>
> Breaking wind in an elevator is [*word*].
>
> Voting this question down is [*word*].

<sub>ok, maybe not the last one...</sub>

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about *uncouth*?

[WordNet Search](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=uncouth) says:

> S: (adj) coarse, common, rough-cut, uncouth, vulgar (lacking refinement or cultivation or taste) "he had coarse manners but a first-rate mind"; "behavior that branded him as common"; "an untutored and uncouth human being"; "an uncouth soldier--a real tough guy"; "appealing to the vulgar taste for violence"; "the vulgar display of the newly rich"

Comment: Ah hah! that's the word I was looking for!

Comment: Is this a common word known to most native speakers?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - It is within the UK, a touch archaic but not so much that it would stop me using it in conversation.

Comment: You wouldn't hear it on the street, but it'd be understood. Still a weird choice.

Comment: It's not uncommon in the U.S.

Comment: I'm not very inclined to vote up an answer by trolldad :P

Comment: Hardly applies to all of the examples though (only the nose and elevator examples).

Answer (score 16):

'frowned upon' sounds just right to me. It's general enough to fit all your cases. I don't think a two word locution is breaking the rules here.

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps, simply inappropriate?

Comment: I think that “inappropriate” implies a dependency on context or at least time of execution that does not fit well with the examples.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe taboo.  Except for the socks with sandals one.  I'd have to go with forbidden or illegal.  (At least it should be)

Comment: Taboo is much to strong for the examples he gave.

Comment: "taboo" Thank you so much. I have no idea why I could not remember this word.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you're looking for the adjective *verboten*?  If that's a bit too strong, you might try *gauche*.

Answer (score 9):

**Not done** is a good term for this.  Going to a random internet reference site, [YourDictionary.com](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/not-done) defines it as *socially unacceptable, improper*:

> Bringing along two friends without asking, that’s just not done.

It also describes it as *[first half of 1900’s]* — but in my experience, it’s still absolutely current in British English.  It may be no longer widely used in American English.

Comment: I also like its variant, "not the done thing", or (usually ironically "not the Done Thing".)  I first saw the term in *[Arthur Rex](http://www.amazon.com/Arthur-Rex-Legendary-Thomas-Berger/dp/0316091464)*, when Mordred is trying to foment a rebellion: he saw Camelot for the first time and hated it, because "It reeked of the Done Thing" (or something like that; I don't have my copy to hand.)  I'd never heard the phrase, but I understood it immediately, and it seemed to capture an entire system of thought/life/society in one phrase.

Answer (score 7):

What's wrong with *rude*? (at least for examples 1 and 3).

Answer (score 7):

I believe the word you are looking here is:

**Improper**

From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/improper

> —Synonyms 
>   1–3.  inapplicable, unsuited, unfit. 2.  indecorous. Improper, indecent, unbecoming, unseemly  are applied to that which is unfitting or not in accordance with propriety. Improper  has a wide range, being applied to whatever is not suitable or fitting, and often specifically to what does not conform to the standards of conventional morality: improper diet; improper behavior in church; improper language. Indecent,  a strong word, is applied to what is offensively contrary to standards of propriety and especially of modesty: indecent behavior, literature. Unbecoming  is applied to what is especially unfitting in the person concerned: conduct unbecoming a minister. Unseemly  is applied to whatever is unfitting or improper under the circumstances: unseemly mirth.

Answer (score 4):

*Uncivilized*? Definitely for the downvote, and I think suits the others as well.  The Russian version, '*nekulturny*' is quite a bit stronger, and I've seen it a few times in English.

Answer (score 2):

This answer to your question is reprehensible!

Answer (score 2):

Picking your nose is *rewarding*.

Wearing socks with sandals is *weird*.

Breaking wind in an elevator is *unavoidable*.

Voting this question down is *mean*.

But to answer your question: horrible is another option.

Answer (score 2):

Normal people usually say "frowned upon" for this scenario, if you're describing how society is:

```
Picking your nose is frowned upon.
Wearing socks with sandals is frowned upon.
Breaking wind in an elevator is frowned upon.
```

"Discouraged" may be used in contexts where the speaker is trying harder to actually get you to not do these things.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference would be *disfavored*. It means generally viewed with disfavor or disapproval. That's almost an exact match, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

*Discouraged* is the word I want to fill that blank with. Not strictly an adjective though.

Comment: It's as much an adjective in this context as is "gone" in "it's gone".

Comment: Well, I'm not a linguist, and I could be completely wrong, but I thought that using "discouraged" in this context (as natural as it would sound to me) would technically be using it as a past participle, and thereby making a passive-voice sentence that would have had any of my former high school English teachers reaching for their red pen of disapproval. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My mother would always use the phrase "infra dig" for things like this. Literally, beneath one's dignity.

Comment: My Mother would usually just give me a clip around the ear ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Infra dig** - Literally means 'beneath one's dignity', but also used to imply unacceptability.

See [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-inf2.htm)

Comment: And who actually says this?

Comment: @Tomalak My mum uses it frequently, however, the OP requested suggestions for suitable phrases and didn't specify the need for words in common usage

Answer (score 1):

I believe many things that are "frowned upon" would generally *be considered poor form*.

For example, picking your nose in public is poor form. Rolling up the resultant boogers, and eating them, is even worse form.

Answer (score 1):

How about: **common**? It's a word often used by the British to express disdain and disparagement. Sometimes used in unison with "muck" as in: "Look at him, picking his nose and "breaking wind" like that. He's **as common as muck**!"

I wouldn't use it with someone who wears socks under his/her sandals though.

[common](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/common)

> definition: 6. Unrefined or coarse in manner; vulgar: behavior that branded him as common.

[common as muck](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+common+as+muck)

> "an impolite way of describing someone who is from a low social class
>   You can tell from the way she talks she's as common as muck."

Answer (score 0):

What about **despicable**? It's the first word that came to my mind... Maybe it's a bit too strong but here you have the synonyms:

> *contemptible, loathsome, hateful, detestable, reprehensible, abhorrent, abominable, awful, heinous; odious, vile, low, mean, abject, shameful, ignominious, shabby, ignoble, disreputable, discreditable, unworthy;* 
>   **informal** dirty, rotten, lowdown, lousy; beastly;

Also **woeful** and **pitiable** can be included.

Comment: *Despicable* and its synonyms are **way** too strong for this.

Comment: As you can see I said it myself, but I thought I could give him a wider view. Plus, I also included woeful, which is not that strong or at least this is how I see it, also considering its translation in my language.

Comment: My point is that they're not "*a bit too strong*", but "*way way **way** too strong*". As in, incorrect. (I also don't think *woeful* and *pitiable* would work too well, but they're acres better than *despicable* and its ilk.)

Comment: @Martha: +1 for “acres better”.  Best comparative I’ve seen in a while, by several bushels.

Answer (score 0):

"tasteless" is my first guess, which upon further consideration is not a 100% hit.

"proof for bad education" is my second guess.

Third is "suboptimal", being quite an understatement, but transporting the message with a bit of humor, and leaving enough room for interpretation that the socks-in-a-sandal-wearers are not really hurt, yet reach those who hate that combination.

Fourth is the German word "abstossend" in English, which as far as I know is "abhorrent", or "repellent". The German pick is absolutely appropriate, but I am not sure about the Enlgish word.

Comment: Downvote, but no desriptive comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about **uncivilized** or **uncivil**?