# Polite synonyms for "a——hole-ish" behavior

Tags: synonyms, politeness

Are there any polite synonyms for *asshole-ish* behavior? A good synonym would probably have about the same impact and wouldn't send people looking for their dictionaries.

Comment: Do you need a specific part of speech?

Comment: Nouns or adjectives will do.

Comment: It would help if you could explain how the person or entity is asshole-ish. Being asshole-ish can mean different things to different people. A rude person could be considered an asshole. So could an arrogant or a mean person.

Comment: In the UK, "arsey".

Comment: @Steve314: Let's not give the Yanks a misleading impression of us Brits! Most of us wouldn't actually say that *arsey* is a "polite synonym" for *asshole-ish*!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I live near Chatham, Kent - around here, general everyday offensiveness is about as polite as you can hope for ya thick bas... er, sorry about that.

Comment: In the absence of any clarification from OP on exactly what *kind* of "asshole-ish behavior" he has in mind, I don't see much point to this question. It makes quite a difference to me whether I'm discussing the recent behaviour of the finance industry at a dinner party, or telling a drunk at the bar what I think of him chatting up my date. Except if that bar was in Chatham, where I wouldn't bother with the verbals. Just lay in with fists and feet, the only language they understand there.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19779/8019

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *lay in*?

Comment: @Noah: [lay into someone](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lay-into) *attack someone physically or with cruel words because you are angry with them*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but yours is *lay in*, is that probably a typo?

Comment: @Noah: Of course not! The difference between *in, into,* and *in to* has probably been covered on ELU, and there are borderline cases, but my usage of [laid in with](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22police+laid+in+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is perfectly normal.

Comment: I might have used following : I couldn't stoop down to amoeba intelligence,but you are being yourself and we know it will be hard to beat you at your trade and experience has made you better at that albeit you are a larger one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Contemptible behavior* or *base behavior* convey contempt without vulgarity. But I think it will be impossible to quite satisfy your requirement for a word with “about the same impact”. I doubt that vulgarity can be matched for impact by anything but blasphemy – and that only when your audience is religious.

Comment: God forgive me, but now I'm curious what blashphemy would convey the meaning of *asshole-ish* behavior.

Comment: That's a new question, I suppose – I was just making the point about relative impact.

Comment: Actually, depending on your audience, you won't be able to find anything that comes close to blasphemy in impact. They'll be agast!

Answer (score 35):

While I don’t use that word myself, like most profanity, its meaning is not very precise. It is used to mean many different things which is only sometimes informed by the context. I’ve seen (or heard) the word used to mean all of the following.

- arrogant
- mean-spirited
- hateful
- rude
- self-centered/self-absorbed
- condescending
- inconsiderate
- intolerant
- self-promoting (especially at the expense of others)
- stingy
- greedy
- argumentative
- hurtful
- abrupt, forward, or tactless in speech

Comment: This is the answer. Too many different kinds of behaviour may be described as "asshole-ish".

Comment: Most assholes are afraid of getting hurt, so they become obessesed with getting power or control, or they offend others before others have a chance to offend them.  We need more words to describe this kind of obnoxious behavior

Comment: I consider the tone of the first sentence of this answer superlatively "asshole-ish."  Just kidding! :p

Comment: Thank you, but in my opinion and obviously it is only that, I think the right synonym would be a word that means all of 8 of your 14 plus others.  (Which I why there might be a need for a single synonym if only it could be found.)  Since I'm not any authority I am not going to say which 8.

Comment: @Broiyan, my point in listing all of the above was to say that you would have to pick the exact meaning you wished to convey before picking a single synonym.

Answer (score 26):

*Boorish* is a pretty common option.

Comment: With optional accessory "uncouth".

Comment: Not that I'm familiar with the word, but also feel like "boorish" has more of an "insufficently refined for the situation" kind of feel. Like someone who thinks it's appropriate to bring their own beer to a dinner party.

Comment: @broiyan: It may be true that only 3% of Americans know the word *boorish*. And quite possibly 99% of them would understand *asshole-ish* even if they'd never actually seen the "word" before. But that doesn't alter the fact that *boorish* is a perfectly valid word, and *asshole-ish* is best left for inarticulate assholes to use if they know no better.

Comment: If truly only 3% of Americans have heard of the word *boor* or don't understand *boorish* then there is more of an illiteracy problem than I thought there…

Comment: @broiyan if that example is the context of the word you're looking for, you should add it to your question.

Comment: *Boorish* appears about as frequently in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) as *taupe*, *busybody*, *fecund*, and *pliant*. (I had no idea *fecund* was so common.) I don’t know how many people know it, but the number could not possibly be as low as 3%.

Comment: I would guess less than 3% of North Americans know the word boorish. Boorish and uncouth might be more synonyms for unrefined than asshole-ish in my opinion. Asshole-ish suggests there is not a lack of self-awareness.

Comment: @broiyan: I've lost count of the number of times I've heard *I might be an asshole, but at least I* **know** *I'm an asshole!* Which somewhat undermines the proposition that assholes are normally self-aware (and suggests maybe I spend too much time hanging around with the wrong kind of people! :)

Answer (score 14):

I would probably use the word *intolerable*, whose meaning is both clear and precise. Assholes can’t be tolerated.

Other similar options I’d consider would be *unspeakable*, *reprehensible*, and *abhorrent*.

Also, if you feel like basic synonyms for bad/awful lack force, you could always add a strengthening adverb. Calling someone’s behavior *truly rotten*, while kindergarten-friendly, is a serious accusation if leveled with the proper gravity.

In light of OP’s search for words both more basic and more emotional, I'm adding *heartless* and *soulless* to my list.

These alternatives to *asshole-ish* were made thinking about OP’s example in a comment about the behavior of the financial industry. I wasn’t really thinking about the general “jerk” sentiment.

Comment: Good efforts, however, "intolerable" IMHO lacks force.  "Unspeakable" is seen off with a "nobody asked you to speak".  "Reprehensible" -- yawn.  "Abhorrent", where's my dictionary.

Comment: Obviously, you know your audience. In my world, though, those are forceful words. The adjective *intolerable* is about as strong as they come.

Comment: Some assholes can be tolerated. Some assholes HAVE to be tolerated.

Comment: If asshole-ish behavior were truly and universally not tolerated it would be dying off. Not my observation.

Comment: Perhaps we have different tolerance levels... ^_^

Answer (score 11):

I would call asshole-ish behavior “rude”.

Comment: "Knowingly rude" might also sound about right but probably fails to convey the level of offence taken, IMO.

Comment: If he or she means to be rude, then perhaps "mean" would fit better.

Comment: How about *antisocial*?

Comment: Rude is quite specific. A person who is manipulative and destructive may be an asshole, but is not rude.

Comment: "Antisocial" works until it's a group of assholes socializing at the expense of others.

Comment: I think the manipulated and property owners would disagree with you, @DJClayworth.

Answer (score 4):

In a business context, *unprofessional* is the usual euphemism that I see used. Otherwise, *rude* or *insensitive* both get the idea across.

Answer (score 2):

Reasonably polite yet quite damning is the word *foolishness.* With slightly more impact yet just as understandable is *idiocy.*

Answer (score 2):

The word that comes to mind is *jerk*.

(I’m surprised no one has said this thus far. Any reason for not?)

Comment: because it is not polite, I guess... XD

Comment: Maybe not... but certainly more polite than `asshole`

Comment: I really don't see the difference between calling someone jerk or asshole... Maybe I am too polite or my English is not very subtle xD

Comment: Where I come from, `ass` is considered profanity/swear word. And therefore, anything that contains the word instantly becomes far less polite.

Comment: Where I come from, jerking is far more profane that showing your ass :p

Comment: Err... thats not a primary definition of jerk. jerk - sudden movement.; A way to prepare meat; an unlikable person, especially : one who is cruel, rude, or small-minded; Also, a physics term.

Comment: Of course it is not the primary definition! The same as an asshole primary definition is the anus, and not a person... ¬¬ I think I'm done here, as the system suggests, this is taking too long. Good luck the next time you call someone jerk while trying to be polite.

Comment: Came here from google and it's exactly what I needed.  Good job +1

Answer (score 2):

I think *highly objectionable* might serve your needs. It communicates that the object of your ire is behaving in a way that *you* consider unacceptable and probably rude. I think this is a good fit for *asshole-ish* because calling someone an asshole mostly communicates that *you* don’t think they are behaving as a mature adult should.

> Her behavior at dinner was *highly objectionable*; she offended just about everyone at the table.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you wrote

> Example: “The financial industry exhibits *asshole-ish* behaviour.”

If that is the context of your word, one could say:

- The financial industry exhibits *predatory* behaviour.
- The financial industry exhibits *heartless* (or *cold-hearted*) behaviour.
- The financial industry exhibits *callous* behaviour.
- The financial industry exhibits *ruthless* behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer is *odious*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends the kind of asshole you are dealing with, for *asshole* really is a convenient shortcut for a variety of people exhibiting an annoying behaviour. Concerning the ones I usually deal with, I enjoy using terms such as *negatively combative* or *harmfully confrontative*.

Answer (score 1):

*Arrogant* or *rude*, depending on your flavor of asshole.

Comment: Please, lets not use "asshole" and "flavour" in the same sentence.

Comment: @chris I didn't even notice until you said that... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines psychopathy as

> a mental disorder characterized primarily by a lack of empathy and remorse, shallow emotions, egocentricity, and deceptiveness

Which are all asshole attributes.

Generally, an *asshole* is a fast driver behind you, who tries to push you to go faster. A *moron* is a slow driver in front of you who won’t speed up no matter how much you ride their tail.

Comment: In other words, the moron is anyone in front of the asshole?

Comment: @mickeyf - Precisely.

Comment: If someone's an asshole firstly it wouldn't be polite to call them a psychopath, and secondly it might not be accurate to call them a psychopath, unless _they really are_.

Answer (score 1):

*Troll*:

> One who purposely and deliberately (that purpose usually being self-amusement) starts an argument in a manner which attacks others on a forum without in any way listening to the arguments proposed by his or her peers. ([*Urban Dictionary*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=troll))

This term seems to be gaining use outside forum environments.

Answer (score 1):

As @makerofthings7 suggests in a comment, I think that *[obnoxious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obnoxious)* is the perfect synonym for *asshole-ish*.

It is polite, almost aggressively so, a reasonably good synonym for *most* of [Andrew Neely’s suggestions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46084/is-there-a-polite-synonym-for-asshole-ish-behavior/46120#46120) and I expect it is reasonably well known.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that *arrogant* or *rude*.