# Word that can be used instead of frowned upon?

Tags: synonyms

Im writing an english paper about the impact on students who fail standardized tests and I'm trying to say that failing or being labeled as remedial is "frowned upon" in society, but i don't want to use "frowned upon". help!

Comment: Also see   [What is the word for an action that is “considered to be frowned upon”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19779),

Comment: What's wrong with "politically incorrect"?

Comment: I don't think *uncouth*, the selected answer to the "duplicate" question, can be used in OP's context: "Failing or labelled as remedial is considered *uncouth* in society" just doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: OP, I can see that the word you're looking for is different than the answer for the "duplicate" question. I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "discouraged", or even "not advised"?

Answer (score 2):

Would you frown upon "stigmatized"?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Thesaurus for [frowned](http://thesaurus.com/browse/frowned?s=ts) .
You can use [gawked](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/gawk?q=gawked) or even [sneered](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sneer?q=sneer) would work fine in your case. Use the Thesaurus link above to pick from the many options. I would even use 'negatively speculated' in society or even [condemned](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/condemn?q=condemn) in society (if its that serious!).